# Multiple Marks with ACF Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm trying to make a Google Map that shows multiple custom markers. I currently have a repeater field setup named 'Map', within that repeater is a Google Map named 'google_map', and a Description text box named 'description'.

I used the code from the ACF Google Map page, but it's only showing one marker.

```
<?php if( have_rows('map') ): ?>
<div class="acf-map" data-zoom="16">
    <?php while ( have_rows('map') ) : the_row(); 

        // Load sub field values.
        $location = get_sub_field('google_map');
        $title = get_sub_field('description');
        $description = get_sub_field('description');
        ?>
        <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo esc_attr($location['lat']); ?>" data-lng="<?php echo esc_attr($location['lng']); ?>"></div>

        </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me work this out?

I was using all the code from this page: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/

But when I use the 'Helper Code' I just get a greyed out map that doesn't show at all. So I used this code instead:

```js
(function($) {
 
function render_map( $el ) {
 
 // var
 var $markers = $el.find('.marker');
 
 // vars
 var args = {
  zoom  : 10,
  center  : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  styles: [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
 };
 
 // create map          
 var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
 
 // add a markers reference
 map.markers = [];
 
 // add markers
 $markers.each(function(){
 
     add_marker( $(this), map );
 
 });
 
 // center map
 center_map( map );
 
}
 
/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 4.3.0
*
*  @param $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param map (Google Map object)
*  @return n/a
*/
 
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {
 
 // var
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
 
 // create marker
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position : latlng,
  map   : map
 });
 
 // add to array
 map.markers.push( marker );
 
 // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
 if( $marker.html() )
 {
  // create info window
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content  : $marker.html()
  });
 
  // show info window when marker is clicked
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
 
   infowindow.open( map, marker );
 
  });
 }
 
}
 
/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 4.3.0
*
*  @param map (Google Map object)
*  @return n/a
*/
 
function center_map( map ) {
 
 // vars
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 
 // loop through all markers and create bounds
 $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){
 
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
 
  bounds.extend( latlng );
 
 });
 
 // only 1 marker?
 if( map.markers.length == 1 )
 {
  // set center of map
     map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
     map.setZoom( 7 );
 }
 else
 {
  // fit to bounds
  map.fitBounds( bounds );
 }
 
}
 
/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 5.0.0
*
*  @param n/a
*  @return n/a
*/
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.acf-map').each(function(){
 
  render_map( $(this) );
 
 });
 
});
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
<style>
 .acf-map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 border: #ccc solid 1px;
 margin: 20px 0;
}

/* fixes potential theme css conflict */
.acf-map img {
   max-width: inherit !important;
}
 </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9lUxdvbkLlrNmVmInFPdE71jQFCC3K7A"></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a website that explained a little better, basically copied their code and it worked: https://www.dgtlnk.com/blog/acf-google-maps/

Here is my code in-case the link stops working:

```js
<script>
(function($) {
 
/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 4.3.0
*
*  @param $el (jQuery element)
*  @return n/a
*/
 
function render_map( $el ) {
 
 // var
 var $markers = $el.find('.marker');
 
 // vars
 var args = {
  zoom  : 7,
  center  : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  styles : [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
 };
 
 // create map          
 var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
 
 // add a markers reference
 map.markers = [];
 
 // add markers
 $markers.each(function(){
 
     add_marker( $(this), map );
 
 });
 
 // center map
 center_map( map );
 
}
 
/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 4.3.0
*
*  @param $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param map (Google Map object)
*  @return n/a
*/
 
function add_marker( $marker, map ) { 
    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
    var icon = $marker.attr('data-img');
    
    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map,
        icon        : icon,
    });
 
    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );
     
    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });
 
        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {          
 
            infowindow.open( map, marker );
 
        });
    }
 
}
  
/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 4.3.0
*
*  @param map (Google Map object)
*  @return n/a
*/
 
function center_map( map ) {
 
 // vars
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 
 // loop through all markers and create bounds
 $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){
 
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
 
  bounds.extend( latlng );
 
 });
 
 // only 1 marker?
 if( map.markers.length == 1 )
 {
  // set center of map
     map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
     map.setZoom( 7 );
 }
 else
 {
  // fit to bounds
  map.fitBounds( bounds );
 }
 
}
 
/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type function
*  @date 8/11/2013
*  @since 5.0.0
*
*  @param n/a
*  @return n/a
*/
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.acf-map').each(function(){
 
  render_map( $(this) );
 
 });
 
});
 
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

```html
<?php if( have_rows('locations') ): ?>
   <div class="acf-map">
    <?php while ( have_rows('locations') ) : the_row(); $location = get_sub_field('location'); ?>
    <?php $location_type = get_sub_field( 'location_type' ); ?>
    
    <?php if ($location_type == 'oxford-college') { ?>
     <?php $type_icon = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/images/Oxford College_Logo.svg'; ?>
    <?php  } ?> 
    
     <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>" data-img="<?php echo $type_icon; ?>">
      <h4><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h4>
      <p class="address"><?php echo $location['address']; ?></p>
      <p><?php the_sub_field('description'); ?></p>
     </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```